# Cannot map shared memory

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, shared-memory

I want to create a shared memory between 2 processes. Therefore I simply copied the snipped from the microsoft page:

Snippet 1:

```
#define BUF_SIZE 256
TCHAR szName[] = TEXT("Global\\MyFileMappingObject");
TCHAR szMsg[] = TEXT("Message from first process.");

void initSharedMem() {
HANDLE hMapFile;
LPCTSTR pBuf;

hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(
    INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,    // use paging file
    NULL,                    // default security
    PAGE_READWRITE,          // read/write access
    0,                       // maximum object size (high-order DWORD)
    BUF_SIZE,                // maximum object size (low-order DWORD)
    szName);                 // name of mapping object

if (hMapFile == NULL) {
    MessageBox(0, "Could not create file mapping object", "Error", 0);
    return;
}
pBuf = (LPTSTR)MapViewOfFile(hMapFile,   // handle to map object
    FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, // read/write permission
    0,
    0,
    BUF_SIZE);

if (pBuf == NULL) {
    MessageBox(0, "Could not map view of file", "Error", 0);
    CloseHandle(hMapFile);

    return;
}


CopyMemory((PVOID)pBuf, szMsg, (_tcslen(szMsg) * sizeof(TCHAR)));
_getch();

UnmapViewOfFile(pBuf);

CloseHandle(hMapFile);

MessageBox(0, "Done init shared mem", "Done", 0);
return;
}
```

Snippet 2(other process):

```
#define BUF_SIZE 256
TCHAR szName[] = TEXT("Global\\MyFileMappingObject");
TCHAR szMsg[] = TEXT("Message from first process.");

void readSharedMem() {
HANDLE hMapFile;
LPCTSTR pBuf;

hMapFile = OpenFileMapping(
    FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,   // read/write access
    FALSE,                 // do not inherit the name
    szName);               // name of mapping object

if (hMapFile == NULL) {
    MessageBox(0, L"Error", L"Could not open file mapping object", 0);
    return;
}

pBuf = (LPTSTR)MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, // handle to map object
    FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,  // read/write permission
    0,
    0,
    BUF_SIZE);

if (pBuf == NULL) {
    MessageBox(0, L"Error", L"Could not map file", 0);

    CloseHandle(hMapFile);

    return;
}

MessageBox(NULL, pBuf, TEXT("Process2"), MB_OK);

UnmapViewOfFile(pBuf);

CloseHandle(hMapFile);

return;

MessageBox(0, L"Done", L"SharedMemoryDone", 0);
}
```

I call the first function in process A, and get the done message. But when I call the readSharedMem function afterwards I get the error message "Could not open file mapping object".

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is your process A still alive when you are trying to open the shared memory section? Besides, what error code do you get when `OpenFileMapping` fails?

Comment: Hint: Never just copy/paste code. Ideally, you should re-type the code, looking up the meaning of anything you don't understand. That's how you learn new concepts.

Comment: Yes both are alive, and error code is 2.

Comment: @CodeMouse92 yeah I know, I just wanted to test something out really quick and implement it better if the theory works

Comment: @QDA, ah, yeah, makes sense.

Comment: Error code 2 translates to *"The system cannot find the file specified."*. This should give you something to work on. Could well be, because snippet 2 has Unicode enabled, while snippet 1 doesn't.

Comment: oh yeah that could it be...how can I disable it?

Comment: You might want to consider having one process start the other process using CreateProcess. In this case, you can pass parameters, such as a handle to the shared memory (as a hex string on a command line), which would eliminate the need for named shared memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I call the first function in process A, and get the done message.

By the time the done message appears, the file mapping object has already been closed, so it no longer exists.

> But when I call the readSharedMem function afterwards I get the error message "Could not open file mapping object".

You left it too late!  You needed to open the file mapping object while it still existed.  That's presumably what the call to `_getch` in the first snippet is for; you're supposed to run the other program at that point, before hitting a key to continue.

Comment: yeah that was it, I thought the same before I went to sleep. I tried it now and the messageBox with "Process2" appears, but there is another problem now. In the messagebox are some chinese letters instead of "Message from first process.". Why are they interpreted wrong?

Comment: Probably you've been messing around with the Unicode settings, since some of the earlier comments suggested they might be your problem.  (For the record, you should *always* be using Unicode mode.)